# How to open web browser and goto a website using groovy language

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

Please do help me with the coding of how to launch a web browser (Ex: Firefox) and then navigate to a website (Ex: [www.gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com)). I know this is very basic but unable to find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to scrape a page then Geb is a good approach.

```
import geb.Browser

Browser.drive {
    go "http://example.com"
    assert title == "Example Domain" 
}
```

The Geb web site has loads of examples.

https://gebish.org/